# Connection pooling on glassfish server running on an Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, glassfish

I had previously developed an application that I deployed on an aws beanstalk. The beanstalk ran on a tomcat server. In order to enable connection pooling in the application I followed this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files/ and wrote a config file to replace the server.xml file of the tomcat running on the ec2 instance. This worked perfectly for me. I am now trying to do the same thing but for an application that runs on a glassfish server. I know that I have to replace the glassfish-resources.xml file of the server but I cant figure out the path to the file on the ec2 instance. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.